# How to search a complete website not indexed by any search engine?

Tags: search, website

I want to search for a keyword on a complete website that is updated recently and not indexed by any search engine, i.e. all pages that exist under a certain URL.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something or couldn't you press `Ctrl-F` in the browser and search on the page?

Comment: @slhck Not the current page. I wan't to search content of  all pages from a particular URL like http://www.codechef.com/teams/view

Comment: Ah I see, by "URL" I thought you meant one page, since a URL in a strict sense only points to one resource.

Comment: Please give reason for down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the website author has some internal search capability, I think that you are out of luck doing this in an easy and automatic way.

Comment: Why not? In theory you could download the website contents locally with HTTrack and search from there, or similar.

Comment: It's not (easy and automatic)....I didn't say you could not do it.